"affect business" vs "effect business"
Is there an actual correct version between "this will affect business" vs "this will effect business?" I've seen both in supposedly formal writing, and read numerous explanations as to when to use each. I'm leaning toward the "affect" version, as, apparently "to affect is to create an effect," but the jury seems out on this one.

Affect means 'have an effect on'. Effect (as a verb) means 'cause something to happen'.

Though 'effect business' is not ungrammatical, meaning 'bring about business', it is so unidiomatic that I'd guess most examples are misuses of 'effect' for 'affect' (= 'have an impact on'). The former meaning would surely be conveyed by 'promote / stimulate / boost / encourage business'.
